# MS sql query different results w/ different user

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have a Microsoft SQL query that returns a different number of rows depending on which user I run it as.  When I remote into my production DB through SSMS with windows auth, I get 656 rows in 3:28 minutes.  When I run it through SSMS on my local machine (connected to the prod DB), logged in as sa, I get 0 rows in 2 seconds.

How is this possible?  I could understand if the query failed as one user due to a lack of permissions, but to return 0 rows and say the query succeeded seems like a really weird behavior.  Is this really the intended behavior of MS SQL?  If it is a permissions problem, it's also strange that somebody set up a user to have more permissions than sa, but that's a different story.

So, can anyone explain how it is possible to get a different number of rows returned depending on which user runs the query?

Edit: I attempted to post my query, but got an error message when I included it in this textbox.

Comment: What does the query do?

Comment: Does your sql have a where clause that references CURRENT_USER?

Comment: Check to see if you have `SET ROWCOUNT` set in SSMS' Tools > Options > Query Execution. Or check the query to see if it makes any conditional logic based on username, permissions, etc. Try posting the query again (or tell us ***what*** error message you got ***specifically*** so we might have some chance at helping with that.

Comment: Does the query call any views, functions or procedures?